# Most Optimal Way to build a nested database instead of reading/writing JSONs to disk

Tags: python, json, mongodb, performance, upsert

I have an API that has nested data that I'm trying to query, it would not be convenient and too much maintenance to flatten this data into an SQL database, I'm querying this data every 10 seconds and I have to do 3 things, each query can return sub-items that belong to an older parent node:

I'm doing this in python and I'm trying to do it asynchronously, at the moment I'm basically:
1 - reading the whole JSON into memory (I have enough RAM).
2 - updating it.
3 - writing it back to disk.

Even though i'm using AIOfiles coupled with JSONdump once jsondumps starts working my whole application is blocked from executing other stuff, so i started exploring other options and it seems that there's JSON in mongoDB, if that's an option, what i want to do:

1 - be able to query items by items that are child nodes of each item in the JSON.
2 - be able to update items in the JSON that already exist using the primary key (upsert?)
3 - be able to write/read the whole dataset quickly without blocking my async application.

Is this the best approach or is there a library or method to do this in a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: use reddis, it will save your data and you can read it 10x faster then regular database e.g. mysql or mongose

Comment: And a SQLite database ? No server and you can do SQL queries .

Comment: I'm already using SQLite but the content of the JSON and the nodes can change frequently, I need to maintain the nesting structure of the objects while reading/writing without having to develop a schema for each json.

Comment: MongoDB allows nested sub-document and array fields (arrays with nested sub-documents) - upto 100 levels. And, the document structure has JSON like (and more) data types. To write a single document with nested data is a one transaction/operation. This is useful in your situation - the points (1) and (2).

Comment: Thank you @prasad_ I'm going to go with MongoDB JSON format, bless :) <3